# Is there a way to revive my dead USB drive?

Tags: linux, usb, ssd, usb-flash-drive

I have this 32GB Kingston USB drive which would be of great use to me, but I have somehow messed it up in the past (it was quite a few years ago, can't remember what I've done, but I surely corrupted it somehow).

Now I've decided to do all in my power to somehow restore it, otherwise I'll have to throw it away I guess.

Okay, enough of chit-chat, facts:

---

- the drive shows up in `lsusb` (strangely enough, only when it's connected to the USB 2.0 slot (the drive is 3.0 capable)
- if I run `# fdisk -l` with the drive connected, it *hangs*
- the interesting part IMO is `dmesg`, look:

  ```
  $ dmesg -wH | grep usb
  [Mar24 21:41] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +0.012873] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1693
  [  +0.000002] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
  [  +0.000001] usb 4-1: Product: DataTraveler 111
  [  +0.000002] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
  [  +0.000001] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 001CC0C60DDABCB1B3260081
  [  +0.000625] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
  [  +0.001931] scsi host6: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
  [Mar24 21:42] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.506879] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.103952] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.016068] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.302172] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.209416] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.104014] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.016086] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.302207] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.329814] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.103980] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +0.519515] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.302064] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.329945] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.103989] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.016118] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.148035] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 15
  [  +0.188354] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.287088] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.103978] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
  [  +3.347501] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.302823] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
  [Mar24 21:43] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.104015] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
  [  +5.016116] usb 4-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
  [  +0.125956] usb usb4-port1: attempt power cycle
  [  +0.000093] usb usb4-port1: cannot disable (err = -32)
  [  +0.000010] usb usb4-port1: cannot disable (err = -32)
  ```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you can do something about it, you will transform a dead drive into an untrustable drive, which is even worse...

Comment: @xenoid I thought this might be a fixable things and I could get a working (trustable) drive back

Answer (score 1):

The error messages you see are on the USB level, not on the storage level. This likely means the controller on the USB stick is damaged in some way (it hangs midway in a USB transaction), and that's not recoverable.

Throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `fsck /dev/[device name]`. You can wipe with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/[device name]` I don't know if these are even relevant if the drive is broken enough.

Comment: Both `fsck` and `dd` fail to do anything, because the drive disconnects and disappears from `/dev/` while they are running (I got some new errors in `dmesg` though: `Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0.000063] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[  +0.000025]  sdd: unable to read partition table`